# Extracting entries from a line into a list in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
myst="Cluster 2 0     13aa,>FZGRY:07872:11201...*1    13aa,>FZGRY:08793:13012...at100.00%2    13aa,>FZGRY:04065:08067...at100.00%"
```

What I want to do is to extract content bounded by `>` and `...`. into a list.
yielding:

```
['FZGRY:07872:11201','FZGRY:08793:13012', 'FZGRY:04065:08067']
```

But why this line doesn't do the job:

```
import re
mem = re.findall(">(.*)\.\.\.",myst)
mem
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Use a raw string for your RE: `r">(.*)\.\.\."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use look arounds to do this.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=>)[^.]+(?=[.]{3})', myst)
['FZGRY:07872:11201', 'FZGRY:08793:13012', 'FZGRY:04065:08067']
```

**Regex**

- `(?<=>)` Positive look behind. Checks if the string is preceded by `>`
- `[^.]+` Matches anything other than `.`, `+` matches one or more.
- `(?=[.]{3})` Positive look ahead. Check if the matched string is followed by `...`

**What is wrong with your regex?**

- `>(.*)\.\.\.` Here the `.*` is greedy and will try to match as much as possible. Add a `?` at the end to make it non greedy.

  ```
  >>> re.findall(">(.*?)\.\.\.",myst)
  ['FZGRY:07872:11201', 'FZGRY:08793:13012', 'FZGRY:04065:08067']
  ```